# Visual Studio Auto Format: Move Bracket

Tags: visual-studio

I'd like Visual Studio to format this

```
if (itRains){
   teleportToSahara(myPapyrus);
}
```

like this

```
if (itRains) 
{
   teleportToSahara(myPapyrus);
}
```

Is there a way to set the format? I read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/999b219z(v=vs.71).aspx but it doesn't say.

Comment: If you want it trough a Visual Studio plugin, install JetBrain's Resharper. It's the best ever!

Comment: @Dr..Net What's a trough plugin?

Comment: It's a spelling mistake. I meant "if you want it through.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just retype the closing brace `}`

Make sure you have the following option *ticked*:

Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/Formatting/General/Automatically format completed block on }

And this one should be *unticked* to get the look you want:

Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/Formatting/Indentation/Indent open and close braces